# Como selecionar um campo no $ui.dropdown do Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera tudo bom??

Eu queria deixar alguns campos já selecionados através de uns id's que eu vou trazer do php.

com essas id's eu gostaria de comparar com as id's já escrita no campo setor "os que estão ocultos" e as id's que forem iguais, seriam apresentados dentro do campo.

"como se alguém estive-se escolhido o tal setor".

obs: nesse dropdowm da para selecionar mais de um campo.

Não sem como fazer mesmo, obrigado pela atenção.

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown(
                            fields: {
                            remoteValues: 'results',
                            values: 'values',
                            name: 'name',   // displayed dropdown text
                            value: 'value'   // actual dropdown value
                        }
                    }
                );

            });

</script>


           <select name="alcada[]" id="setor" multiple="" class="ui fluid search dropdown">
                            <?
                            foreach ($hashSetor as $setor) {
                                if ($setor['setorID'] == $hashEdit['alcada']) {
                                    $selected = 'selected';
                                } else {
                                    $selected = '';
                                }
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?=$setor['setorID']?>"><?=$setor['nome']?></option>
                            <? } ?>
                        </select>
```

[image: Campo de seleção]

Comment: Amigo, dá uma melhorada nessa explicação porque não dá pra entender onde vc quer chegar. Está meio confuso e com erros ortográficos que dificultam muito o entendimento. Aliás, nem dá pra entender. Abs!

Comment: Desculpe , eu já editei o texto.

Comment: Já tentou colocar o `$selected` na option: `<option <?=$selected?> value="<?=$setor?>"><?=$setor?></option>`?

Comment: Não tem lógica isso, eu simplesmente vou colocar o option ...e não setar ele..

Comment: O que está acontecendo aqui... é que eu selecionei um usuário em uma lista e o sistema colocou as informações dele nos campos <inputs> da pagina para que possa editar essas infomações. só que falta eu setar nesse campo de setor quais os setores a qual ele pertence.

Comment: Então... se colocar as options como selected não aparecem listados os setores vindos do PHP?

Comment: Hum.. talvez mas talvez de ruim pois eu eu já estou printando no "foreach" ...más você me deu uma ideia.